# use command `osascript -e 'quit app "Quicktime Player 7"'` with python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, quicktime, osascript

I am using `osascript -e 'quit app "Quicktime Player 7"'` in OSX Terminal to close the Quicktime Player 7 application, which works well, but can't get this same command working using python. What am I doing wrong?

This just runs, but does nothing:

```
command = ['osascript', '-e', 'quit app', 'Quicktime Player 7']
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `quit app` and `Quicktime Player 7` as two list elements will transform the command `subprocess.Popen` executes into something like this:

```
osascript -e 'quit app' 'Quicktime Player 7'
```

`osascript` expects the parameter following `-e` to be "one line of a script" (see `osascript`'s [man-page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html)).
Splitting up the parameters causes `osascript` to execute `quit app` and interpret `Quicktime Player 7` as an argument, thus probably ignoring it.

A simple fix would be the following:

```
command = ['osascript', '-e', 'quit app "Quicktime Player 7"']
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

If you don't want to work with lists/splitting up your commands in the first place, you can use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) to do the work for you:

```
import shlex
command = shlex.split("osascript -e 'quit app \"Quicktime Player 7\"'")
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
```